# When installing an MSI, CREATE DATABASE permission denied

Tags: c#, sql, windows-10, windows-installer, sql-server-2016-express

I have created an MSI file that installs a program. As part of the installation process, I need to create a local database using SQL Server 2016 Express on Windows 10 Enterprise. When I run the MSI, the following error occurs:

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
SQL error number = 262 ==> SQL server = (local)\MYCOMPUTER --> SQL state = 1 --> Error code = -2146232060 --> SQL Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

How can I get past this issue and create the local database? Is there a setting I need to change in SQL Server, or in my code itself?

Googling this question has told me that I need to give the user login the roles of "sysadmin" and "dbcreator", but this hasn't worked. I've disabled these roles for the user for now.

Comment: Are you running the MSI as administrator?

Comment: Do you want to use Windows Credentials or a Username and Password?  What account is the installation process using (and environmental variables).

Comment: @jdweng Username and password. What do you mean by "what account" and "environmental variables"?

Comment: @EdneyHolder Running as admin hasn't made a difference, sadly.

Comment: What account were you using when you ran the MSI.  A user or admin?  If you ran as a scheduled task it may of been run with Sys account that doesn't have any environmental variables set.

Answer (score 0):

In your script add the following

```
USE master;
GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO <LoginName>;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO <LoginName>;
```